# How to use MPVolumeView in order to change Audio output device. Like WhatsApp and hangout

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudiosession

I am trying to achieve the functionality that allows to switch between different audio outputs i.e. Bluetooth, earphone or default iPhone. 
same like whatapps and  and hangouts are doing can anyone suggest me how i should go for it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah finally achieved expected output. preety simple.

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mpvolumeParentView: UIView!


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let mpVolumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: mpvolumeParentView.bounds)
    mpVolumeView.showsRouteButton = true
    mpVolumeView.showsVolumeSlider = false
    mpVolumeView.setRouteButtonImage(UIImage(named: "IMAGE_NAME"), for: .normal)
    mpvolumeParentView.addSubview(mpVolumeView)
}
}
```